# CKAN form field validation

Tags: ckan

I am using form macros to create form fields. But I could not find anything looking at the source code of some of the existing CKAN forms how to set validation rule for a given form field. Any help would be appreciated.

PK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on which form you're customizing. If you're customizing the add/edit dataset form, you need to write an [IDatasetForm](http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/writing-extensions.html#ckan.plugins.interfaces.IDatasetForm) extension. If it's the group form, you want an [IGroupForm](http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/writing-extensions.html#ckan.plugins.interfaces.IGroupForm) extension. There's no plugin interface for customizing the organization form yet, unfortunately.

To see how to write a CKAN extension, checkout the [new writing extensions tutorial](https://github.com/okfn/ckan/pull/943) (currently in development, feedback appreciated), and also take a look at the [example_idatasetform](https://github.com/okfn/ckan/tree/master/ckanext/example_idatasetform) extension that comes with CKAN.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am trying to add a completely new form that does not anyway relate to dataset or group. Recently I found from the source code how to validate some common form fields from the validators.py file.